# Is there an elegant way to unwrap an object wrapped in 2 nested Optionals?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Consider these two classes

```
class EmailService {
    public Optional<String> getEmailAlias(String email);
}

enum Queue {
    public static Optional<Queue> fromEmailAlias(String alias);
}
```

The implementation of the above methods is not important to the question so I have left that out for simplicity.

I want to do this:

```
emailService.getEmailAlias("john@done")
    .map(Queue::fromEmailAlias)
    .ifPresent(queue -> { 
        // do something with the queue instance, oh wait it's an Optional<Queue> :(
    });
```

However, this does not work because `queue` is of type `Optional<queue>` (the same type as returned by `Queue::fromEmailAlias`), so I have this instead:

```
emailService.getEmailAlias("john@done")
    .map(Queue::fromEmailAlias)
    .ifPresent(q-> { 
            q.ifPresent(queue -> {
                // do something with the queue instance
            }
    });
```

Kind of ugly imho.

Changing the signature of

```
public static Optional<Queue> fromEmailAlias(String alias);
```

to

```
public static Queue fromEmailAlias(String alias);
```

is a quick fix, but that would also affect my code in other places which need `Optional<Queue>`.

Is there a nice way to unwrap this nested Optional?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to apply `flatMap`:

```
emailService.getEmailAlias("john@done")
            .flatMap(Queue::fromEmailAlias)
            .ifPresent(queue -> { 

             });
```